# Making ReSharper use m_ convention

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using ReSharper C++ with Visual Studio but it uses some weird naming conventions that I don't like. I want to use [this convention](https://github.com/lefticus/cppbestpractices/blob/master/03-Style.md), which uses `m_` prefixes on class member variables and snake case. They state that `.clang-format` can be used, but I'm not using LLVM, but VS' compiler.

Did someone make a file applying those conventions? Pretty sure most of the people are using them instead.

```cpp
#ifndef RESOURCE_CLONER_HPP
#define RESOURCE_CLONER_HPP

#include <Windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string_view>

namespace resource_cloner
{
    
    class resource_cloner
    {
    public:
        resource_cloner() = default;

        resource_cloner(const resource_cloner&) = delete;

        resource_cloner(resource_cloner&& obj) noexcept
        {
            *this = std::move(obj);
        }

        ~resource_cloner()
        {
            unload();
        }

        resource_cloner& operator=(const resource_cloner&) = delete;

        resource_cloner& operator=(resource_cloner&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            m_source_path = rhs.m_source_path;
            
            return *this;
        }

        void load()
        {
            m_module = LoadLibraryExW(m_source_path.data(), nullptr, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);

            if (!m_module)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Could not open source file.");
            }
        }
        
        void unload() const
        {
            if (m_module)
            {
                FreeLibrary(m_module);
            }
        }

    private:
        std::wstring_view m_source_path;
        HMODULE m_module{ nullptr };
    };
    
}
    
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the naming conventions on the "ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C++ | Naming Style" options page, or choose one of the predefined schemes. That said, using both "m_" as a class member prefix and "t_" as a parameter name prefix is unusual, and none of the major C++ style guides use this convention.